# How to convert a timeformat in YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, javascript-objects

I have a below date format  need to convert it as

```
console.log(new Date(startDate)).toISOString();
console.log(new Date(endDate)).toISoString();
```

I need an output like this 20180928T00000 but which return 2018-11-01T00:00:00.000Z this format.

```
Current Output:
// startDate=2018-11-01T00:00:00.000Z
 //endDate=2018-12-01T00:00:00.000Z

Expected 
// StartDate=20181101T000000 
// endDate=20181201T0000000';
```

Comment: You can use a library like `moment`, or you can just use a regex to replace everything that's not a number

Comment: @user184994 is there any builtin functions in moment to convert this

Comment: Yep, `moment(new Date(startDate)).format('YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS');`

Comment: thankyou one more help after T need to replace the system time  to 000000 and end date should be 235959 as default .

Comment: Then just do `moment(new Date(startDate)).format('YYYYMMDDT000000')` or use `235959` in the `endDate` example

Comment: @user184994Thank you .. your solution  works as expected.

Comment: @user 184944 can you help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53708625/moment-js-interval-for-a-day-in-12-hours-format

Answer (score 0):

You could use Moment.js, however if it is just a once off and  you do not want to import the whole library, I would suggest using **regex** to remove all none letters/numbers, then JS **slice()** method to remove last character.

```
const date = '2018-11-01T00:00:00.000Z'
const result = date.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/g,'').slice(0, -1)
console.log(result) // 20181101T000000000
```