# Moment js interval for a day in 12 hours format

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone, angular2-moment

In 12 hours format,i have to create a interval of 15 minutes in moment which is working fine with 30 minutes interval.

```
var hours = [];
    for (let hour = 0; hour < 24; hour++) {
      hours.push(moment({ hour }).format('h:mm a'));
      hours.push(
        moment({
          hour,
          minute: 30
        }).format('h:mm a')
      );
    }
  console.log( hours);
```

But when work with 15 minutes shows the wrong format.can anone help?

```
var hours = [];
    for (let hour = 0; hour < 24; hour++) {
      hours.push(moment({ hour }).format('h:mm a'));
      hours.push(
        moment({
          hour,
          minute: 15
        }).format('h:mm a')
      );
    }
  console.log( hours);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/remus/rLjQx/

Expected Op: 12:00, 12:15,12:30,12:45,1:00 etc

Comment: Can you edit your question to include expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only pushing in two values per loop. You need to push in four values for *every* hour. One way would be to loop minutes within the hour loop hours:

```js
var hours = [];
for (let hour = 0; hour < 24; hour++) {
  for (let minute = 0; minute < 60; minute += 15) {
    hours.push(moment({hour, minute }).format('h:mm a'));
  }
}

console.log(hours);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```